# Flutter Image can't be assigned to parameter type ImageProvider<Object>

Tags: flutter, flutter-image

```
CircleAvatar(
  radius: 30,
  backgroundImage: Image.asset("images/bg.png"),
),
```

Error:

> The argument type 'Image' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'ImageProvider?'. (argument_type_not_assignable at [love_messenger] lib\main.dart:85)

What should ı do??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```dart
 backgroundImage:AssetImage("images/bg.png") ,
```

```dart
CircleAvatar(
  radius: 30,
  backgroundImage: AssetImage("images/bg.png"),
),
```

Comment: I just wiped data from the emulator and restarted then it worked, but thanks

Comment: While adding assets, make sure to rebuild the app

Answer (score 0):

You need to use ImageProvider like this:

```
    CircleAvatar(
                 radius: 30,
                 backgroundImage: AssetImage('images/bg.png')
```

Or use child property:

```
    CircleAvatar(
                 radius: 30,
                 child: Image.asset("images/bg.png")
```

Have a nice time!